# How to adjust estimation of probability according to new information

Tags: probability, probability-theory, estimation

Suppose $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. The probability of $a_i=j$ is estimated to be $p_{ij}$. The probability matrix might look like this

$$
 P=\left( \begin{matrix}
   .2 & .1 & .2 & .5 \\
   .4 & .3 & .3 & 0  \\
   .2 & .3 & .2 & .3 \\
   .2 & .3 & .3 & .2 
 \end{matrix} \right)
$$

And it's now discovered that $a_1\neq1$ and $a_1 \neq 2$. How should I adjust the estimation?

My attempt to deal with this is to break $p_{ij}$ into the sum of the possibilities of $(n-1)!$ permutations where $a_i=j$, and I'll get 16 equations for 24 variables. $a_1\neq 1$ would mean that $P(1234)=P(1243)=P(1324)=P(1342)=P(1423)=P(1432)=0$, and it will affect other equations. But I don't know how to move on from here.

Comment: In Bayes setting, $P$ is your prior distribution. How $P$ is updated depends on how strong your belief in your prior. In Frequentist setting, it means that how many data are used to estimate $P$. If you use only, say 10 data to estimate $P$, then an additional new data may have significant change to the estimate. Whereas if $P$ is estimated by one million data, then the new estimate may not change much.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you simply don't have enough information to accurately update $P$. For instance, let's suppose when $n = 3$, we had $P_{ij} = 1/3$ for all $i, j$ and we found out that $a_1 \neq 1$ and $a_1 \neq 2$ (i.e. $a_1 = 3$).

Let's look at two cases that satisfy this $P$.

Case 1: All of the $3! = 6$ permutations are equally likely.
In this case, we have that our updated $P$ should be:
$$
P =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Case 2: Each of the permutations 123, 231, 312 have a $1/3$ probability (and all other permutations have zero probability). In this case our knowledge that $a_1 = 3$ dictates that our permutation is 312. We therefore have that
$$
P =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$